# R: find ngram using dfm when there are multiple sentences in one document

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, quanteda

I have a big dataset (>1 million rows) and each row is a multi-sentence  text. For example following is a sample of 2 rows:

```
mydat <- data.frame(text=c('I like apple. Me too','One two. Thank you'),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

What I was trying to do is extracting the bigram terms in each row (the "." will be able to separate ngram terms). If I simply use the dfm function:

```
mydfm  = dfm(mydat$text,toLower = T,removePunct = F,ngrams=2)
dtm = as.DocumentTermMatrix(mydfm)
txt_data = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
```

These are the terms I got:

```
"i_like"     "like_apple" "apple_."    "._me"       "me_too"     "one_two"    "two_."      "._thank"    "thank_you"
```

These are What I expect, basically "." is skipped and used to separate the terms:

```
"i_like"     "like_apple"  "me_too"     "one_two"    "thank_you"
```

Believe writing slow loops can solve this as well but given it is a huge dataset I would prefer efficient ways similar to the dfm() in quanteda to solve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to extract those bigrams, then you could use `tokens` twice.  Once to tokenize to sentences, then again to make the ngrams for each sentence.

```
library("quanteda")
mydat$text %>% 
    tokens(mydat$text, what = "sentence") %>% 
    as.character() %>%
    tokens(ngrams = 2, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    as.character()
#[1] "I_like"     "like_apple" "Me_too"     "One_two"    "Thank_you"
```

Insert a `tokens_tolower()` after the first `tokens()` call if you like, or use `char_tolower()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks! This helps, I changed the outer tokenize() to dfm() so that those bigram terms can be features of my dataset

Answer (score 2):

@Jota's answer works but there is a way to control the tokenisation more finely while calling it only once:

```
(toks <- tokenize(toLower(mydat$text), removePunct = 2, ngrams = 2))
## tokenizedText object from 2 documents.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "i_like"     "like_apple" "apple_me"   "me_too"    
## 
## Component 2 :
## [1] "one_two"   "two_thank" "thank_you"

dfm(toks)
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 7 features.
## 2 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    i_like like_apple apple_me me_too one_two two_thank thank_you
##   text1      1          1        1      1       0         0         0
##   text2      0          0        0      0       1         1         1
```

**Added:**

Then to remove any ngram with `.` punctuation, you can use: the following, which defaults to `valuetype = "glob"`:

```
removeFeatures(toks2, "*.*")
## tokenizedText object from 2 documents.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "i_like"     "like_apple" "me_too"    
## 
## Component 2 :
## [1] "one_two"   "thank_you"
```

Comment: @Jota After tried different method, I finally used `dfm(mydat$text,ignoredFeatures='.')` which will automatically drop those contains '.'

Comment: Yes see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Since `quanteda v0.9.9-3` one can use `(toks <- tokens_tolower(tokens(mydat$text, removePunct = 2, ngrams = 2)))` and `dfm_remove(dfm(toks), "*.*")` instead.